# Git find what changes have been done in a tag for a given file

Tags: git, git-commit

I want to find for my source code file Foo.cpp what all changes has been done in the version tag v3.4.0.

Hope above sentence is good enough to explain my question. actually I have to find all changes in only one file which has been pushed for version tag v3.4.0

Comment: Do you want to know all changes made to a file up to the given revision identified by the tag? `git log ..v3.4.0 -- Foo.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all the change have been done in a tag for a given file:

```
git diff <prev_tag_name> <tag_name> <path/to/filename>
```

git diff v3.3.9 v3.4.0 Foo.cpp

That's it..